# Accents in TeamViewer 11 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, teamviewer, special-characters

I'm having troubles using accents in TeamViewer 11 on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm using a spanish keyboard and my TeamViewer connection is to a Windows 10 Host.

- I can't write charactes like: á, é, í, ó, ú
- I've already enabled 'Send Key Combinations' option without success.
- I have no problems writing accents in gedit or other tools

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: But can you write them successfully into `gedit`?

Comment: Yes I can, I have no problems writing accents in gedit or other tools.

Answer (score 0):

How is the windows 10 setup? Does it also have a Spanish keyboard layout?
If not, can you add it into the layouts?
Under the control panel, you can go to the clock,language,region, and under "advanced" you can change language bar hot keys, to swap keyboards.

If none of this works, there may be another (more difficult) method. Ascii- hold "alt", and type in the ascii code on the number pad for a character, then release alt.(only works on number pad). That may be another work around.
You can find some ascii code in tables at asciitable.com

[image]

Comment: Hi Michael,

thanks for your answer. Yes, windows is setup with a Spanish keyboard layout.

Comment: I thank you for the trick of the ascii code table, but it is not very operative for writing long texts.

Comment: Yes, for long text it can get horrible. If special characters aren't an option over teamviewer simply by typing them, and you need to type a lot of them, I would suggest typing it all in textedit on your local computer. Then copy paste the text into the remote computer. Clipboard works over a remote connection in teamviewer.